# How do I set 4 bytes bit pattern for magic number in Java?

Tags: java, c++, linux, networking

I am working on a network programming on linux machine using C++ and I was wondering how I can set 4 bytes bit pattern for magic number in Java (client). Also how do I set the same bit pattern in c++ co I can compare the one from client with the one on the server side.

Thank in advance..

Edit

So now I have this

```
    byte[] signature = new byte[4];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        signature[i] = (byte) 0xA9;
    }
```

And if I looked at the inside of the array after for loop from the debugger then I have

```
{-89, -89, -89, -89}
```

And I did something like this in C++

```
    uint8_t m_magicNumberBuffer[4];
    magicKeyRead = read(m_fd, m_magicNumberBuffer, SIZE_OF_HEADER);


    if(m_magicNumberBuffer[0] == 0xA9 && m_magicNumberBuffer[1] == 0xA9 && m_magicNumberBuffer[2] == 0xA9 && m_magicNumberBuffer[3] == 0xA9){
        printf("SocketClient::recvMagicKey, Magic key has been found \n");
        break;
    }
```

I somehow works but not sure that I have declared m_magicNumberBuffer and unsigned integer but those were in negative 89 in java. Is this ok to do this in this way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has bitwise operators, for example bitwise OR `|`, bitwise AND `&` and bit shift operators `>>>`, `>>` and `<<`, very similar to what C++ has. You can use those to manipulate bits exactly as you want.

Since you don't explain in more detail what you want to do, I cannot give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you would represent it as

```
byte[] signature=new byte[4];
```

in C++, it would be

```
uint8_t signature[4];
```

You can then access each of the bytes individually as elements of the array.

Both languages support hex codes, so for example, you could do

```
signature[0]=0xA9;
```

in either java or C++ and it will set the first bit to A9 in hexadecimal (which is 10101001 in binary)

Answer (score 0):

When you write to a DataOutputStream you write 8-bit bytes (sign is not important)

```
String filename = "text.dat";
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    dos.write(0xA9);
dos.close();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(dis.readUnsignedByte()));
dis.close();
```

prints

```
a9
a9
a9
a9
```

Java assumes a byte is signed by default, however its is just 8-bits of data and used correctly can be unsigned or mean whatever you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really dealing with is four bytes of raw memory; all you're
concerned with is the bit pattern, not the numeric values.  In eight
bits (the size of a `byte` in Java), `-89` and `0xA9` both have the same
bit pattern: `10101001`.  Because `byte` is signed in Java, dumping the
value will show a negative value, which is rather counter intuitive, but
Java doesn't have an eight bit unsigned type.

(Technically, `0xA9` isn't representable in a `byte`, and trying to put
it in a `signed char` in C++ is illegal.  But Java doesn't care about
such niceties.)